# How can I detect which HP DV6 model I have?

Tags: windows, drivers, hp-pavilion

I just bought a new HP laptop and didn't find the model to install drivers.

In BIOS it says HP Pavilion Dv6 NoteBook PC but when I search for it, it returns a lot of models. I asked HP Website to detect it but it failed as well.

How can detect the model? I don't have model at the back of laptop. How can I install drivers for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend download program called DriverEasy he identifies automatic for all you drivers, without having to specify model is automatic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will find help in this document: [How Do I Find My Model Number or Product Number?](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&cc=us&docname=c00033108)

> HP provides a type of model name near the keyboard or screen, but this name or number is probably not sufficient to get proper support for your computer. These names or numbers often represent a series of many notebook computers that look similar, but have different options and parts.
>
> This document describes how you can find a more appropriate model number that better represents your exact type of HP Notebook PC. You can use the model number (also called a product name) to download drivers, find helpful documents, or get on-line support.

Answer (score 0):

Find the serial from the BIOS. Then search Google to find the model using the serial for HP.

Comment: Did that work for you?